# How to fix JIT debugger "Visual studio is not registered to be notified when an unhandled exception occurs in a native application"

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, windows-11

Windows 11

This message is displayed when vsjitdebugger.exe is executed "Visual studio is not registered to be notified when an unhandled exception occurs in a native application"

One way for me to produce that message is in a command line window. Run vsjitdebugger notepad.exe.

This isn't what I'm actually trying to debug! Its just a simple example.
My final goal is to be able to use the Image File Execution Options register to debug my executable whenever it is executed.

I have run `vsjitdebugger /regserver`

I have repaired the install.

I have updated to the latest version. Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.10

In the registry entry `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug` I have created the `DWORD` value `Auto` and set it to 1.

And the same for `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug`

In the registry entry `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting` I have created the `DWORD` value `Disabled` and set it to 1.

And I'm still getting the same error message.

Does anyone have another solution?